# Android: Error connecting Android app with Database using php and json

Tags: java, php, android, sql, json

My android app needs to send a string, and based on that, needs to get a response from the database.
I have a php that receives the string from the app, queries the database, and returns the response using `echo json_encode($response_array);` which works fine on the browser and echoes in a json object format.

However, In the app, I am using Volley. The php array $response_array above sends multiple strings which i need to display in the app textview.

I have set up volley in the gradle dependencies.

However, on running the app from my phone (which is connected on my laptop hotspot), the error i get is "null". This is the sample code from the app.

```
    TextView o,t;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private static final String URL = "http://172.25.33.189/fadapp/mirror.php";
private StringRequest request;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    o=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tryOne);
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tryTwo);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonobject.names().get(0).equals("name")) {
                    o.setText(jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    if(jsonobject.getString("stat").equals("1")) {
                        t.setText(R.string.inText);
                        t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
                    } else {
                        t.setText(R.string.outText);
                        t.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hashMap.put("speid", "database query string here");
            return hashMap;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you grant the intenet access to the app with ?

If you are hosting from your laptop you may need to open the port 80, to be sure that the problem isn't yor Volley set-up try to query for example google and print the response that should be a 200 http code

Comment: You're welcome! If you do not want these problems, open the port 80 on your router and on your Firewall. Having the firewall disabled isn't a good idea